# Click on desktop application (settings) button it shall open laravel web application and shall authenticate automatically

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, frameworks

I am building a desktop application that will have a settings screen in web. If the user click on the settings button it shall open laravel web application and shall authenticate automatically. So I need a deeplink to login directly into the application and redirect user to settings page.

Is there any way to solve this scenario with laravel Auth or any further suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I guess that for deep link you mean "very long and difficult to guess url".

I suggest you to manage the access using an authentication token (is generally used for API, but also "remember me" functionality use a token stored in cookie) and make it possible to configure the token in the desktop application.

this allow you to:

- disable a token at any time
- create different tokens for different users
- much better security compared to hidden url